# Ramanujan and Other Fields

Tags: soft-question, math-history, k3-surfaces

Ramanujan's works also included K-3 Surfaces (although it was discovered much later as mentioned [here](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/10/151014132457.htm) and [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0536/94328b0128cedafa063a6a03d904830dfe86.pdf)) which in the recent years have found their way into physics as one can see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07610).

I wanted to know that did Ramanujan ever work on applying his theorems to solve questions in fields such as economics, physics etc. (something like finding analytical solutions of unsolved differential equations) or tackling specific physics, economics etc. problems instead of working on abstract math etc.

Comment: Ramanujan did not "apply his theories". He did not develop theories at all, but something else, much more creative, but less formal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I meant to say theorems I'll update

Comment: Not an expert on Ramanujan.Googled a bit as you may have done.Cf. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-mathematical-contributions-of-Ramanujan. Physics not mentioned.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yeah I saw a few websites online but none authentic. Quora can't be trusted very much for the same

Comment: There is a Ramanujan Society. Perhaps worthy to check with them. http://rsmams.org/

Comment: @DietrichBurde: He did not apply his theories but its rather incorrect to say that he did not develop his theories. His most important work was in the field of elliptic and theta functions and he developed it much farther than any of his predecessors (Legendre, Jacobi) all alone. The irony is that he did not have money to buy paper so that he could record all this development. And thus he preferred only to store the final results.

Comment: Ramanujan had no interest in any other subjects. Any biographies of him or his collected papers do not have any mention of physics at all. His mathematical development was also unique as he used basic algebra and calculus only. He did not have any idea of complex analysis and modern algebra (groups, Galois theory etc).